# Adding 3D Text in Video editing

Tags: objects, 3d-view, video-sequence-editor, text-object

Is there a way to make the text that you can add in the video editor apear to look 3D? I want to add 3D knock out text on top an existing video. Or is it possible to create the 3D text in the 3D viewport and somehow place it on the video in the Video editor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, create your 3D text, enable the film *Transparent* option in the *Render* panel:

[image]

It will give you a transparent background when you'll render:

[image]

If you plan to animate the 3D text, export it as a series of *PNG (RGBA)* pictures in order to keep the transparency:

[image]

Then in the *Video Sequencer*, press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> to add the text, whether it is animated or not. Then put the strip it will create over the video strip:

[image]

Comment: I created the 3D text and exported it first as PNG(RGBA) Pictures, then I added the sequence in the video editor and exported it with the settings: FFnoeg Video/RGBA/ Quicktime/ QT rle / QT animation and set film to transparent. But when I import the .mov file into premiere pro it tends to crash a lot. It plays the tranparent text video but after a while it starts to crash my computer. Is this a common issue or is there a way around this?

Comment: I don't know enough about movie formats, perhaps you should import a series of PNG into Premiere Pro?

Comment: Thanks I didn't know it was possible to create a image sequence out of PNG's in Premiere Pro. I think it did the trick it doesn't seems like I'm getting any errors anymore.